# Does using the <base> element have the same caching behavior as using absolute links?

Tags: html, css

I have a static multi-page website with some custom fonts. I ran into a lot of "flash of unstyled content" while using `@font-face` and I learned it was because I was using relative links in my `src` attribute, so I changed them all to absolute links. Everything loads faster, and I don't have those flashes anymore.

However, developing locally is a bit of a chore now, as I have to find-replace-all to turn the absolute links back to relative ones while I work. I discovered the `<base>` HTML tag recently, and being able to comment out a single line when developing locally rather than doing find-replace all would be a lot easier, but I don't want that performance hit.

Does using the semantic HTML element `<base>` cache resources in the same way that using absolute links inside my `src` attributes does?

Comment: @Kaiido Is there a different reason why I see an immediate, noticeable difference in asset loading when using absolute links vs. relative?

Comment: Without seeing your code and server config it's hard to say, but there shouldn't be any difference between a relative URL and an absolute one regarding the cache.

Comment: I'm using neocities to host my website. I don't have access to anything server facing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.